# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing mypackage: %1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide

Tags: python, path, package, anaconda, jupyter

I would like to use a package with jupyter notebook, but I have this error :
`import pyAgrum`
`ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pyAgrum: %1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide.`

I freshly installed last anaconda distribution with python 3.9, and installed pyagrum following this line `conda install -c conda-forge pyagrum`

I think I understand that anaconda is looking for the wrong pyAgrum package (I have several python versions). When I use 'where python' from anaconda prompt, i get this :

```
C:\Users\my\path\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\my\path\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
C:\Users\my\path\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

When I launch python from anaconda prompt then use

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

I get :

```
['', 'C:\\Users\\my\\path\\Documents\\WPy-3710\\python-3.7.1.amd64\\Lib\\aGrUM-master\\aGrUM-master', 'C:\\Users\\my\\path\\Documents\\WPy-3710\\python-3.7.1.amd64\\Lib\\aGrUM-master', 'C:\\Users\\my\\path\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyAgrum', 'C:\\Users\\my\\path', 'C:\\Users\\my\\path\\Anaconda3\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Users\\my\\path\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\my\\path\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\my\\path\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\my\\path\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\my\\path\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\my\\path\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\my\\path\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

I suppose the problem is that the pyAgrum package from python 3.7 come before the anacondas packages. But I can't figure out how to change this order. I have windows 10 but I don't know how to change this specific environment variable (I didn't find it the environment variables of Windows).

Comment: I finally went back to my problem, and found a temporary solution. I simply had the correct path with "sys.path.insert(0, "\\path\\to\\my\\module") at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

DLL issues [often result from mixing channels](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels). Since Conda Forge is completely standalone, it is recommended to create an environment that prioritizes Conda Forge. Something like:

```bash
## include all packages you want at creation time
conda create -n foo -c conda-forge python pyagrum ipykernel
```

Note that `ipykernel` is not strictly necessary, but OP tagged Jupyter implying that running this as a kernel is desirable.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, it did not work. :( I used the command `conda create -n foo -c conda-forge python=3.9 openssl pyAgrum ipykernel` to create a new environment. However, when I launch the notebook from the Anaconda Navigator using the new environment, I still encounter the same error when trying to import pyAgrum. Additionally, when I activate the new environment in the Anaconda prompt, I still receive the same information about the path (python 3.7).